# TinyMCE issue with Schema object

Tags: tinymce

Whenever I click on the media plugin, the popup shows up but the Type: select list is empty.  In my Javascript console, I see an error of which this is the screen shot:

https://skitch.com/e-etdebruin/eqqgb/developer-tools-http-et.ekklesia.current.dev-vendor-tinymce-plugins-media-media.htm-3.4.0.4

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElementRule'

The code snippet is in tinymce/plugins/media/js/media.js:

```
    getMediaTypeHTML : function(editor) {
        function option(media_type, element) {

            if (!editor.schema.getElementRule(element || media_type)) {

                return '';
            }

            return '<option value="'+media_type+'">'+tinyMCEPopup.editor.translate("media_dlg."+media_type)+'</option>';
        }
```

I believe we are on one of the latest versions of Tiny.

Any guidance as to what I messed up?

Here is my config:

```
tinyMCE_GZ.init({
  plugins : 'advimage,advlink,table,fullscreen,paste,media,spellchecker,imagemanager,template,insertform',
  themes : 'advanced',
  languages : 'en',
  disk_cache : true,
  debug : false
});

tinyMCE.init({
  theme : 'advanced',
  plugins : 'advimage,advlink,table,fullscreen,paste,media,spellchecker,imagemanager,template,insertform',
  mode : 'textareas',
  editor_deselector : 'mceNoEditor',
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'center',
  theme_advanced_layout_manager : 'SimpleLayout',
  theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,cut,copy,pastetext,pasteword,selectall,separator,spellchecker,styleselect,formatselect',
  theme_advanced_buttons2: 'link,unlink,anchor,separator,image,insertimage,media,template,insertform,separator,bullist,numlist,blockquote,outdent,indent,separator,code,separator,removeformat,cleanup,separator,fullscreen',
  theme_advanced_buttons3: 'tablecontrols',
  apply_source_formatting : true,
  valid_elements: 
  spellchecker_languages : '+English=en',
  extended_valid_elements : 'script[src|type],form[action|method|id|class|enctype]',
  valid_children : '+body[style]',
  theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
  theme_advanced_resizing : true,
  theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
  theme_advanced_blockformats : 'p,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,div',
  external_image_list_url : '/vendor/tinymce/monk/clientImageList.php',
  external_link_list_url : '/vendor/tinymce/monk/clientLinkList.php',
  media_external_list_url : '/vendor/tinymce/monk/clientVideoList.php',
  flash_external_list_url : '/vendor/tinymce/monk/clientFlashList.php',
  flash_wmode : 'transparent',
  relative_urls : false,
  content_css : '/vendor/tinymce/monk/contentCss.php',
  template_external_list_url : '/vendor/tinymce/monk/clientMonkletList.php?monklets=true',
  template_popup_width : '400',
  template_popup_height : '250'
});
```

I would appreciate any feedback.